# How to go to a View in Shared folder from a View in Home folder in MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to access a `PartialView` in `Shared` folder by clicking an `Html.ActionLink` `HelperMethod` present on a view in `Home` Folder as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "~/Views/Shared/_AddBranch.cshtml");
```

with fail. I dont want to add a new controller to achieve this but I don't mind replacing `Html.ActionLink` with another tool if I need to. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be generating an anchor tag which points to the view file directly without an action method. Ideally you should create an action method throuh which you will render the view.

If you are trying to render some re-usable view. You should use `Html.Partia`l method in your main page

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_AddBranch.cshtml")`

Razor will include the HTML markup for the `_AddBranch.cshtml` when it renders your main page

If you want to pass a model/viewmodel to the partial, you can use this overload

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_AddBranch.cshtml",Model.YourModelYouWantToPass)
```

Assuming `YourModelYouWantToPass` is a property of the model of your main page and your partial view is strongly typed to the type of `YourModelYouWantToPass` property.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance especially for introducing me to the powerful idea of using `ActionMethod` feature of MVC.